# DOM Tree rendering consequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I wonder how is it important for DOM tree element to be on the right place?

`<style>` should be inside `<head></head>`

`<div>` should be inside `<body>`

`<body>` should be inside `<html>`

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").css("display", "none").before("<p>Loading...</p>");
});
```

It turns out to be that after document download we cover  and put in front of it a kind of a block, that informs about page loading.

What reaction browsers can show to such construction? I checked it in Firefox 6, IE 9 - no problems!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that if your DOM does not conform to a standard, there is no standard way defined for how the layout should be handled by the web browser.

Therefore the browsers are free to render the webpage as they wish; which makes it harder for you to design a webpage that displays consistently across allllllll web browsers.

Comment: HTML5 defines graceful and standard ways of handling invalid markup.